# mount and remount as read-only a file in linux

Tags: readonly, mount-point

I want to mount a file as read-only and anybody cant write to this file.

I research in internet and find some commands:

```
 mount -o remount,ro /dev/sda6 /srv/html
```

and

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda6 /srv/html
```

but this for file system and partitons.

How to mount a file as read-only?

Thank you.

Comment: `chattr +i /path/to/file`

Comment: Thank you , but I do not want to use the chattr.

Answer (score 0):

How about a mount bind?

```
$ touch a
$ echo "Hello World" >> a
$ pwd
/home/nwani
$ mkdir -p /tmp/readonlydir
$ sudo mount -o ro,bind /home/nwani/ /tmp/readonlydir/
$ echo "Hello World" >> /tmp/readonlydir/a
-bash: /tmp/readonlydir/a: Read-only file system
$
```